# How could this jQuery code be improved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm a jQuery newbie and for now I rely on modifying existing scripts, but in the near future I plan to dig into the depths of jQuery API.

So, I'm using a jQuery snippet, which does a couple of things inside navigation menu dropdown with 5 submenus, which are dynamically populated with checkboxes.

On the bottom of the each submenu I have 4 buttons:

- select all (selects all checkboxes inside submenu), id="checkAll"
- deselect all (deselects all checked checkboxes inside submenu), id="uncheckAll"
- cancel (deselects all checked checkboxes if any and toggles submenu style display to none), id="cancelSelection"
- confirm (toggles submenu style display to none), id="confirmSelection"

So, for this buttons to work I put together this peace of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // dropdown 1
    $("#mega-menu-item-1 #checkAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-1 .ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-1 #uncheckAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-1 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-1 #cancelSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-1").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-1 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
      $("#mega-menu-item-1 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-1 #confirmSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-1").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-1 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    // dropdown 2
    $("#mega-menu-item-2 #checkAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-2 .ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-2 #uncheckAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-2 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-2 #cancelSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-2").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-2 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
      $("#mega-menu-item-2 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-2 #confirmSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-2").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-2 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    // dropdown 3
    $("#mega-menu-item-3 #checkAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-3 .ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-3 #uncheckAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-3 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-3 #cancelSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-3").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-3 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
      $("#mega-menu-item-3 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-3 #confirmSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-3").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-3 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    // dropdown 4
    $("#mega-menu-item-4 #checkAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-4 .ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-4 #uncheckAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-4 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-4 #cancelSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-4").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-4 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
      $("#mega-menu-item-4 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-4 #confirmSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-4").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-4 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    // dropdown 5
    $("#mega-menu-item-5 #checkAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-5 .ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-5 #uncheckAll").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-5 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-5 #cancelSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-5").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-5 .ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");
      $("#mega-menu-item-5 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
    $("#mega-menu-item-5 #confirmSelection").click(function () {
      $("#mega-menu-item-5").removeClass("mega-hover");
      $("#mega-menu-item-5 ul.sub").toggle();
    });
});
```

Each submenu has id #mega-menu-item-1/2/3/4/5, so I repeat each button action for every submenu item.

To explain it a little bit further:

1. Class .mega-hover is added to parent html element by megamenu script, which I'm using when submenu is displayed (it has state display: block). So I must also remove this class on closing the submenu with .removeClass("mega-hover").
2. Class .ez-checked is used by jquery snippet for checkbox styling so each checkbox element is wrapped inside div with class .ez-checkbox. When checkbox is checked, additional class .ez-checked is appended, so on cancel or uncheck I must remove this class with .removeClass("ez-checked").
3. As I mentioned in point 1 I'm using megamenu script, which also toggles display state of submenu. So on #confirmSelection or #cancelSelection I must toggle it with $("#mega-menu-item ul.sub").toggle();

I'm sure this isn't the smoothest way to do all of this, so I'm asking experienced developers to suggest, how could this code be optimized, I guess there is a lot of repeating at least.

Comment: You have several elements with the same ID (e.g. `#checkAll`). This is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by working with classes instead of id's.
You can simplify the checkall click like this for example:

```
$(".checkAll").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".mega-menu-item");
    parent.removeClass("mega-hover");
    $("ul.sub", parent).toggle();
}
```

Comment: #mega-menu-item id's are inherited from megamenu script and I can't change that and not break the menu. Also isn't best practice to use id selectors as they are faster then classes because id maps directly to a native JavaScript method, getElementById()?

Comment: ID's should only occur once per page as Felix King mentioned. They should be avoided when working with single-page interfaces, for example, because you don't know which elements are loaded at any particular time. You can easily alter my script to not use a class based .mega-menu-item. just do .closest('div') for example if it's the closest div parent.

Comment: Ups, I've missed Felix's answer. Of course, it's not valid HTML, I've changed all button and script id's to classes. Everything is working so far.

In next step I will try to implement your suggestions.